# MS SQL Server: how to determine which field is causing Arifmetic error

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling, sql-update

I have an update statement, which updates a lot of fields in the table. I get the error

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
>   The statement has been terminated.

It does not show which exactly field is causing the problem. 
Is there ANY way to get this information from SQL Server? 
Assume that checking each field manually, one by one, is not an option.

Comment: Can you show the statement?

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Do all of the updates need to be applied simultaneously? If not, consider using some form of binary chop (across columns and/or rows) to narrow down the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say whether or not your columns allow `NULL` values.

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
D1 DECIMAL(2,2) NOT NULL,
D2 DECIMAL(2,2) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO T VALUES(0.99,0.99)
```

Then

```
UPDATE T SET D1=0.33, D2=2.0
```

gives the highly informative

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

But

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
UPDATE T SET D1=0.33, D2=2.0
```

Gives the slightly more informative

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'D2', table 'MyDb.dbo.T';
>   column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

Telling you the specific problem column.